# how to display data of object containing multiple array?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I want to iterate all the array from below screenshot

Comment: So you fetch some data (that looks like the image you uploaded) and need to render those 4 arrays with the same graphical item?

Comment: @Auticcat, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose the below code :

```
    var obj = {a: [1,2,3], b: [1,2,3]};
    for (let key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        let val = obj[key];
       return val.map((data) => {
    console.log(data);//this will loop through every array like 1,2,3 likewise 
    return(
      <Text>{data}</Text> 
      )
    });
      }
    }
```

Inside the text im printing data so that you can view in app
Hope its clear. feel free for doubts

Comment: main_menu/appetizer contains 4 different objects like 0,1,2,3 so i want to display each object data. so how to do that?

Comment: push everyobject in an array first, loop through array and then traverse each object in array by the code above.

Comment: will you please elaborate with my example.